# Stack Exchange needs rules for where to post questions considered off-topic

Tags: feature-request, scope

There should be a set of rules and guidance for communities to know where a question can be posted.

Recently I posted [a question](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/69644/when-was-the-ligature-%c3%a6-removed-from-daemon-and-replaced-with-ae) on History Stack Exchange, but it was closed as "off-topic", even after following the guidance in this [Meta Stack Overflow answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343030/this-tag-is-history?noredirect=1&lq=1) which stated that it should be posted there.

There should be an easy to access set of rules to post otherwise "off-topic" questions and get answers without being passed around all of Stack Exchange.

Comment: https://history.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @Warcupine this has nothing to do with history stack exchange, it has to do with ALL the exchanges communicating and making rules between themselves so we know where we CAN post, not what we cannot. This is also why it's a feature request because such a feature does not exist for coordination.

Comment: There are over one hundred sites, they all have their own community driven topicality. What you are asking for isn't really feasible.

Comment: Generally they do communicate it, in their help centres. You should definitely read the "How to ask" section of that on any site on the network *before posting*. That will clue you up on all the basics if you follow the links.

Comment: @Warcupine what you're really saying is the platform is no longer suited to meet the demands of the information culture, and that may very well be. Maybe stack exchange is dead.

Comment: @NationWidePants Stack Exchange was always just Stack Overflow plus some bonus sites, this will never change. So even if some sites are "dead", this can't mean SE as whole is dead.

Comment: @NationWidePants do remember that the platform *expects you to do research* before posting. And that includes what is on- or off-topic for a given stack. The network would truly be dead when that's no longer a requirement as you want it to become. You want to be personally handed over the information with no actual effort by yourself.

Comment: @VLAZ I didn't say that, I said there was a conflict in the guidance presented between metas.

Comment: I'm afraid people that are active on one site aren't generally very good at knowing what's on topic elsewhere.

Comment: @NationWidePants you were told that you should have checked the information about a stack before asking and lamented you had to, declaring the network "dead". I don't know how else to interpret your words.

Comment: @VLAZ It was in response to the statement that the site is incapable of providing solid guidance on where to post a stated question. If the site has fallen into such bureaucracy that it can no longer aid in finding answers and the metas CANNOT, if by design or feature, fulfill the same set of guidelines you've outlined for questions then the site is dead, it is no longer fulfilling its own mission statement. That is going off  
Warcupine's statement regarding it's (Stack Exchange's) inability to provide features to aid in this request.

Comment: @NationWidePants The purpose of Meta.SO is not to guide your usage of History.SE. Your assessment that is based on a plain wrong premise. As mentioned, there are over a hundred stacks around the network. Making sure *each* of them has correct and accurate information about *each other one* is a Sisyphean task as each stack is free to change in the mean time by changing or adding new policies. If *you* think it's possible, then are *you* volunteering to maintain this information? If not, then why do you expect others to do it?

Comment: @VLAZ Create tags that go between exchanges, for instance, could be one thing that could be added to aid in this. There are many tags that are used between exchanges. There are plenty of ways to connect different exchanges that are developmental rather than administrative.

Comment: @NationWidePants which...leaves as at square one, doesn't it? You *still* need to check how to use the stack you're pointed at.

Comment: @VLAZ I did, and that wasn't sufficient: it still doesn't meet the needs of the user base.

Comment: @VLAZ "you still need to check how to use the stack you're pointed at." > Fair enough, though there is enough to be gained by stating that the one that does the pointing needs to do the same checks. I believe comments recommending Code Review for posts that aren't suitable for Code Review are a well-known problem on SO, and IPS regularly gets migrated/crossposted posts based on comments that are just not researched too. You can't put all the onus on one party here.

Comment: @Tinkeringbell Well, no. But any recommendation should implicitly come with "if that's allowed under the rules". It's literally impossible to generically say "all questions that match criteria X go to site Y". There would always be exceptions. And the rules might change in the mean time, too - when criteria X was mentioned 6-8 years ago, it might have been correct but not any more, for example. Lest we stop recommending any site whatsoever, there is never going to be a fully totally correct way to say "This belongs to that stack".

Comment: I've updated the Stack Overflow Meta question linked in the question above to try to make it clearer you can't just post anything you like on History Stack Exchange when it's off topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Off-topic *where*? Each site has its own rules. If a question is off-topic everywhere, it shouldn't be on the network.

Comment: NWP, Your original question is interesting, here some links I examined while researching: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%C3%A6mon_(His_Dark_Materials) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%86  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_(computing) https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=daemon&year_start=1800&year_end=2005&corpus=en-2012&smoothing=3 - it's an anthropomorphization, and could be asked on   https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ligature

Answer (score 21):

Here are some rules you can follow:

1. Do not blindly follow the advice people give you about another site. That applies to this answer as well, and in general to all answers here to [site-recommendation](/questions/tagged/site-recommendation) questions. I'm stealing the next two rules from its tag wiki:
2. Keep in mind that not all types of questions belong on a Q&A site, and not everything can find a home here at Stack Exchange.
3. It's often helpful to go to https://stackexchange.com, enter some terms in the search bar in the upper-right, check out the sites that show up in the results, and read their help pages. The full list of sites is also available at https://stackexchange.com/sites.
4. If you still don't know where to ask your question, you can ask a [site-recommendation](/questions/tagged/site-recommendation) question here. Please have a look at the [tag wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/site-recommendation/info) for how to improve the chance that you get a good answer.
5. Before posting your actual question on one of the network's sites, do another search there, and be sure to read the Help Center article "What topics can I ask about here?"

> without being passed around all of Stack Exchange

Yes, I agree that is not a pleasant feeling. That's exactly where the current procedure with [site-recommendation](/questions/tagged/site-recommendation) is for. This community has the most diverse user base in the network and even a veteran like me is sometimes surprised by the answers other users come up with.

Comment: It's not a matter of the above, it's a matter of the inability to link people between exchanges, through tags or otherwise, to get answers to questions from more than one subject area. If I ask a question on StackOverflow I get answers only from StackOverflow, and only StackOverflow. This is a platform to link experts in various areas to exchange ideas, but we have gaps inherent between us removing our ability to properly get the answers we need, and the solution we've had to remove people doing this is to close questions as off-topic, rather than linking people and resources.

Comment: Well, as you experienced, people tried to link resources in your case, but that failed. Therefore, the procedure is more or less as I described.

Comment: the link I mentioned, and you are stating failed, is not the linking I mean: the platform could link similar tags between stack exchanges so experts in different fields of the same topic could reply. Or the ability to select exchanges in which to share a question so people don't need to rewrite the question and ask within each exchange. That way, each exchange can vote to close a question independently, but the person asking can get a wider audience for answers and greater potential to get a solution/answer.

Comment: @NationWidePants A question is usually more important to the person asking it than anyone else. Therefore, it makes sense to make the person asking a question do a little extra work to find out if they are asking in the right place, rather than having people post a question simultaneously on multiple sites and have *multiple people on all those other sites* have to put in effort to determine which one it belongs on.

Comment: @BryanKrause If a person goes through the effort of doing said research and sites determine they don't like it for whatever reason, as it is an arbitrary feeling, not a set of rules which has a well defined state for some questions, a person asking a question should be able to ask multiple platforms the same question as to what they feel applies for their question, if research and thought was put into the question, to get  the best response and feedback possible. This platform shouldn't be so strict and bureaucratic that it couldn't accommodate flexibility between platforms with the same tag.

Comment: @NationWidePants I disagree, what you propose needlessly wastes the time of people who are trying to make these sites the best they can be. Your own question may be important to you, but the site itself has bigger goals than that, and those goals include keeping quality high enough that people want to stick around and browse and answer other people's questions. Without people who answer it doesn't matter if questions are open or closed.

Comment: @BryanKrause My proposal improves "browse(ing) and answer(ing) other people's questions", and depending upon how they decided to develop the solution it could be seamless to users. I don't think your response provided a clear reason why you "disagree"

Answer (score 17):

The post you've linked, a burnination request for the [history]-tag on Stack Overflow states:

> #### Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?
>
> No. History questions should be asked on History Stack Exchange, and questions about programming history are also, as I already mentioned, off-topic. There may be programming concepts called "history" (like browser history), but there are more specific tags for those.

The answer here is twofold:

- History questions should be asked on History Stack Exchange,
- and questions about programming history are also, as I already mentioned, off-topic [on SO].

The question you posted falls into the second category IMHO. (The change of wording of a programming term.) Falling in that second category, doesn't automatically make it fall in the first category too. So I feel that that's where the confusion started.

If you're unfamiliar with a site, it is best to not take some random strangers word for it, especially when it is phrased in generic terms like this is. The best course of action here would be to firstly check a site's /help/on-topic.

On [Historie's](https://history.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) you can see that they accept questions about the following topics:

- Historical events
- Cultures and historical practices
- Famous people
- Ancient Languages
- Human Prehistory
- Factual current political history questions
- Historiography

This aligns pretty well with what history is taught in most schools, and doesn't really have a mention of any (computer)technology. If you are still unclear about your question being on topic, you could always ask a [site-recommendation](/questions/tagged/site-recommendation) question.